# Session not destroyed upon clicking logout button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

i have been trying to destroy a session using an ajax function upon upon clicking the logout button, but it does call the function in my php script through the ajax function

**AJAX function**

```
<div id="logout_btn" class="btn-header transparent pull-right">
    <span>
         <a href="<?php echo APP_URL; ?>login.php" title="Sign Out" onclick="logoutck()" ><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a> 
    </span>

    <script>
        function logoutck() {
            var sendingData = { jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "logout"};            
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",        
                    url: "/New_Dashboard/dashboard_html/server.php",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(sendingData),
                    success: function( msg ) {
                        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg.result );
                    }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**PHP function to destroy the session**

```
function logout(){
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION)){
        session_destroy();
    }

    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: Take the code out of that function, on your logout php file. It will work. Instead of using Ajax, just set the `href` on the link for that file. This is not a job for Ajax!

Comment: the problem is function logout is inside a another script called fop.php, therefore when i give the href it right away redirect there and nothing happens

Comment: Your problem is that the function `logout` isn't being executed. Using the header `Location: login.php` in your Ajax call will be useless. You can either rewrite as I told you or you can try to add `location.reload(true);` in your `success` function.

Comment: can somebody find me a way to call this logout function... that will be more than enough

Comment: Write `logout();` right below, in a new line. Or completely remove the function declaration. You don't need to use `$.ajax`. `$.get` is enough, no need for `jsonp` too.

Answer (score 0):

Make a link like this:

```
<a href="logout.php" >Logout</a>
```

Your logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:login.php");
?>
```

Comment: Why would you need to unset the $_SESSION['id'] after destroying the session?

Comment: If user put id in session while login function.with this we can set id as blank or unset  here.

Comment: I was under the impression that session_destroy() destroys all data associated with the current session. Is this true?

Comment: the problem is function logout is inside a another script called fop.php, therefore when i give the href it right away redirect there and nothing happens

Comment: can somebody find me a way to call this logout function... that will be more than enough

Comment: I'hv faced problems with login while making projects in php.The $_SESSION variables are still set in the same page after calling session_destroy() where as this is not the case when using unset($_SESSION) or $_SESSION = array().

Comment: I do know what you mean, but here you are redirecting the user so unsetting $_SESSION['id'] is redundant.

Comment: OK David you mean session_destroy();//this clear all data related with all variables.
unset($_SESSION['id']);//this clear data and session with particular variable

Comment: Yeh both options are correct and having that unset() in the code wouldn't have made a difference, just an extra line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If login is successful, then set `$_SESSION['login'] = 1;` in your login validation .php file. Then to logout use following code.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 unset($_SESSION['login']);
 header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to edit the a tag like this:

```
<div id="logout_btn" class="btn-header transparent pull-right">
    <span>
         <a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a> 
    </span>
</div>
```

Also take out all your JavaScript as it is not needed.

Now you need to ignore your logout function and just create a new file called logout.php. This will contain:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: login.php");
    exit(0);
?>
```

This is probably the most simple example of logging a user out using sessions. You may need to add to it to suite your needs.